# how to check device orientation when we move from one view controller to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Suppose, i am in the viewcontroller which is in the landscape mode. when i push new viewcontroller how to check  previous viewcontroller orientation and change orientation of this view?

Please Help.

Thank You.

Comment: You can go through this link it may help : Device Orientation Reference [**link 1,**](http://ddeville.me/2011/01/getting-the-interface-orientation-in-ios/)
[**link 2**](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling)

Answer (score 4):

It must be done in automated way. In each view controller you must define this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

in which you can set in what orientation your controller may be.

In iOS 5 or earlier `UIViewController` handles only portrait orientation by default.
To handle other possible orientations you must implement this method in your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    return YES;
}
```

You might also want to define methods to handle rotation:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

or

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Or do it in automated way.

You can read more [**here.**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Handling View Rotations
>
> In iOS 6, your app supports the interface orientations defined in your
>   app’s Info.plist file. A view controller can override the
>   supportedInterfaceOrientations method to limit the list of supported
>   orientations. Generally, the system calls this method only on the root
>   view controller of the window or a view controller presented to fill
>   the entire screen; child view controllers use the portion of the
>   window provided for them by their parent view controller and no longer
>   participate in directly in decisions about what rotations are
>   supported. The intersection of the app’s orientation mask and the view
>   controller’s orientation mask is used to determine which orientations
>   a view controller can be rotated into.
>
> You can override the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation for
>   a view controller that is intended to be presented full screen in a
>   specific orientation.
>
> In iOS 5 and earlier, the UIViewController class displays views in
>   portrait mode only. To support additional orientations, you must
>   override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method and return
>   YES for any orientations your subclass supports. If the autoresizing
>   properties of your views are configured correctly, that may be all you
>   have to do. However, the UIViewController class provides additional
>   hooks for you to implement additional behaviors as needed. Generally,
>   if your view controller is intended to be used as a child view
>   controller, it should support all interface orientations.
>
> When a rotation occurs for a visible view controller, the
>   willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:,
>   willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:, and
>   didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: methods are called during the
>   rotation. The viewWillLayoutSubviews method is also called after the
>   view is resized and positioned by its parent. If a view controller is
>   not visible when an orientation change occurs, then the rotation
>   methods are never called. However, the viewWillLayoutSubviews method
>   is called when the view becomes visible. Your implementation of this
>   method can call the statusBarOrientation method to determine the
>   device orientation.
>
> Note: At launch time, apps should always set up their interface in a
>   portrait orientation. After the
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method returns, the app
>   uses the view controller rotation mechanism described above to rotate
>   the views to the appropriate orientation prior to showing the window.

Comment: `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` are methods, not classes.

Comment: These methods dont work!!

Comment: These work only when u change the orientation after the view is loaded and not before loading.

Answer (score 0):

As per your questions it is not very clear can you please explain your requirement and why you want to do this in more detail.

As per my understanding you can check for the current orientation of the device in your new view controller that will be the previous oreintation of the device in the previous view.

Regards
Rahul Dubey